# How do we get college_name from url and fetch value from database in ci using where college_name='$college_name' in ci?

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller:

```
public function company_details()
{
    $company_name = $_GET['company_name'];  
    $this->load->model('members/Userquery');    
    $data   = array();
    $data['result'] = $this->Userquery->company_info($company_name);
    $data['navbar']='members/user/navbar';
    $this->load->view('members/user/company_info',$data);
}
```

view:

```
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <title>Assigned Job | ATS</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
       <?php $this->load->view($navbar);?>
       <?php foreach($result  as $r); { ?>
           <p><?php echo $r['company_name']; ?></p>
       <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

model:

```
public function company_info($company_name) {           
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT  p.*,c.*,ct.* FROM post_job as p left join company as c on c.company_id=p.company_id left join citymaster as ct on ct.cityid=p.location where company_name='$company_name' ORDER BY p.job_post_id DESC"); 
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

In this code I want to fetch value with college_name but It show Message:

> Undefined index: company_name

so how could I remove this.

Comment: change this `where company_name='$company_name'` with where `c.company_name='$company_name'` and try.

Comment: Your URL must not have `company_name`. Check if the value is there before trying to use it here `$_GET['company_name']`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: as you are storing all fetched data to `$data['result']` but not using that !!!!

Answer (score 1):

change this to

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT  p.*,c.*,ct.* FROM post_job as p left join company as c on c.company_id=p.company_id left join citymaster as ct on ct.cityid=p.location where company_name='$company_name' ORDER BY p.job_post_id DESC");
```

to

```
c.company_name='".$company_name."'
```

Comment: as per the SO rules, You can give this little change through the comment also.

Comment: I cannot add comment Since I don't have 50 rep :(

Comment: Ohh.. i didn't see that, njoy

Comment: I have got same problem Message: Undefined variable: company_name

Comment: @samorten, maybe you have to check your code again, you did couple of mistakes in your code.

Comment: check all the comments and start trying to resolve as people point you.

Comment: sam did you checked whether the company name is coming up correctly(not empty) in controller?

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating directly on the `$result` variable.

Just try this

```
$result = $data['result'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
public function company_details()
{
    $company_name = $this->input->get('company_name');
    //echo $company_name;   //check here
    $this->load->model('members/Userquery');    
    $data   = array();
    $data['result'] = $this->Userquery->company_info($company_name);
    $data['navbar']='members/user/navbar';
    $this->load->view('members/user/company_info',$data);

}
```

Model :

```
public function company_info($company_name)
{           
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT  p.*,c.*,ct.* FROM post_job as p left join company as c on c.company_id=p.company_id left join citymaster as ct on ct.cityid=p.location where c.company_name='$company_name' ORDER BY p.job_post_id DESC"); 
return $query->result_array();
}
```

In view: you have to remove semicolon at the end of foreach statement. Because semicolon represents the end of loop....

```
<html lang="eng">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <title>Assigned Job | ATS</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <?php $this->load->view($navbar);?>
   <?php foreach($result  as $r){ ?>
   <p><?php echo $r['company_name']; ?></p>
   <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```